# Axis label in base R plot using expression() command for superscript and Greek letter

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to plot this plot. I would like to have
[image]
on the X axis.

```
plankton_tow <- data.frame(DO <- c(-1.2, -0.8, -0.5, -1.5), depth = c(10, 20, 30, 40))
core_tops <- data.frame(DO <- c(-2.0, -1.6, -1.3, -2.5), depth = c(50, 60, 70, 80))

max_depth <- max(c(plankton_tow$depth, core_tops$depth))
plot(plankton_tow$DO, max_depth - plankton_tow$depth, xlim = range(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO)), ylim = c(0, max_depth),
     xlab = expression("δ"^18" O [‰]  vs. PDB"), ylab = "Depth [m BSL]", 
     pch = 16, col = "black", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
points(core_tops$DO, max_depth - core_tops$depth, pch = 16, col = "red")
```

I have used expression() for this but it only gives this output

[image]

and I get the error: unexpected string constant in: expression("δ"^18" O [‰]  vs. PDB")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close-- try `expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB")`

```
plot(plankton_tow$DO, max_depth - plankton_tow$depth, 
     xlim = range(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO)), 
     ylim = c(0, max_depth),
     xlab = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"), # Fixed
     ylab = "Depth [m BSL]", 
     pch = 16, col = "black", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")

points(core_tops$DO, max_depth - core_tops$depth, pch = 16, col = "red")

# adding axes
axis(1, at=seq(from=min(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO)), to=max(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO)), by=0.5))
axis(2, at=seq(from=0, to=max_depth, by=10), las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: that was a easy fix thank you